# Getting the actual this reference to the task state machine

Tags: c#, task, state-machine, internal

I'm playing with the idea of tampering with the state of a tasks internal state machine, but i'm having trouble finding a way to actually access the state machine reference within my task method.

```
class Test
{
    async Task IndexAsync()
    {
        var nottheactualtype = GetType(); //This references the "Test" class, but this operation is actually located in the nested state machine class named "IndexAsync", in the method "MoveNext()".
        var actualcalledmethod = new StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod(); //This shows the actual method currently being run: IndexAsync.MoveNext().
        //But how do I get the reference to my current IndexAsync class?
    }
}
```

How can I get access to the reference of the generated state machine currently being run?

Comment: Does it have to be within the method itself? I have a lot of code doing this sort of thing in https://github.com/jskeet/DemoCode/tree/master/Abusing%20CSharp/Code/FunWithAwaiters which may help you, but it doesn't tend to get the state machine *within* an async method.

Comment: I Believe so. At a certain location within the async method, I want to see which state in the state machine is being run. There is more to it than that, but the essence is that I want to access the members of the currently running state machine. The members I can access via reflection, and I can access the type of the generated class. But I can't seem to find a way to access the actual reference to it.

Comment: Okay, I think I've come up with something, but I need to try it out...

Comment: If you need this level of fined grained control over the state machine, then you shouldn't be using the compiler generated state machine, and you should be writing your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take first method call from your class on stack as variant:

```
var nottheactualtype = GetType();
var actualcalledmethod = new StackTrace().GetFrames().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetMethod().ReflectedType == nottheactualtype);
```

Comment: Sorry, but that gives the same result as `this.GetType()`, which is quite not what i'm after. The problem is that the compiler obscures the "this" reference in order to hide the compiler-generated state machine class. Using the StackTrace, I can get access to the type instance of the state machine class, but I need access to the actual running instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's nasty, and it's not guaranteed to work (it depends on implementation details) - but this works for me... it basically provokes the state machine to pass a continuation to an awaiter. We can then get the state machine out of the continuation delegate's target.

Ugly, ugly, ugly code... but it does work for me :)

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using static System.Reflection.BindingFlags;

public class StateMachineProvider
{
    private static readonly StateMachineProvider instance = new StateMachineProvider();

    public static StateMachineProvider GetStateMachine() => instance;

    public StateMachineAwaiter GetAwaiter() => new StateMachineAwaiter();

    public class StateMachineAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
    {
        private Action continuation;

        public bool IsCompleted => continuation != null;

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            this.continuation = continuation;
            // Fire the continuation in a separate task.
            // (We shouldn't just call it synchronously.)
            Task.Run(continuation);
        }

        public IAsyncStateMachine GetResult()
        {
            var target = continuation.Target;
            var field = target.GetType()
                              .GetField("m_stateMachine", NonPublic | Instance);
            return (IAsyncStateMachine) field.GetValue(target);
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        AsyncMethod().Wait();
    }

    static async Task AsyncMethod()
    {
        int x = 10;
        IAsyncStateMachine machine = await StateMachineProvider.GetStateMachine();
        Console.WriteLine($"x={x}"); // Force the use across an await boundary
        Console.WriteLine($"State machine type: {machine.GetType()})");
        Console.WriteLine("Fields:");
        var fields = machine.GetType().GetFields(Public | NonPublic | Instance);
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{field.Name}: {field.GetValue(machine)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
x=10
State machine type: Test+<AsyncMethod>d__1)
Fields:
<>1__state: -1
<>t__builder: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder
<x>5__1: 10
<machine>5__2: Test+<AsyncMethod>d__1
<>s__3:
<>s__4: System.Reflection.FieldInfo[]
<>s__5: 6
<field>5__6: System.Reflection.FieldInfo <field>5__6
<>u__1:
```

Comment: I agree the force of continuation is quite ugly, but the approach is brilliant and definitely worth checking out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to pass the reference or instance of your IndexAsync class into the Test class.

Another option is to assign it to a private backing field through reflection, although I would prefer the first option, since reflection can be slow.

If you share more of your code it will be easier to identify how to do it in your case.

Comment: No sorry, it doesn't work. The nested IndexAsync class is compiler-generated ([this blog entry explains quite well how the internals of an async task works: [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-1-compilation)), so I can only access it in runtime.